# How to disable Jack Option and enable Java8 features in a android

Tags: android, android-studio

**I am using the Android studio version:**

[image]

---

**I am using the Settings:**

[image]

---

**I am getting the error:**

[image]

---

### But the doc says i can remove the jack options, Why I am not able to remove it

[image]

Comment: Are your build tools outdated? Please post your build.gradle file for this module and project